# How do you configure HTTP connector attributes when using the embedded Tomcat in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

By default when uploading a file (as a PUT request) to Tomcat it will read the headers and then *if* the client sends a `Expect: 100-continue` header it will straight away reply back with the `HTTP/1.1 100` response to prompt the client to send the file. This can be controlled on the connector with the `continueResponseTiming` attribute outlined in the [HTTP connector documention](https://ci.apache.org/projects/tomcat/tomcat9/docs/config/http.html)

However in Spring Boot this settings can't easily be configured with [application properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-server).

What is the best way to configure attributes like this?

Answer (score 1):

By using a [`TomcatConnectorCustomizer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/tomcat/TomcatConnectorCustomizer.html) bean, here's a simple example:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatConnectorCustomizer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public TomcatConnectorCustomizer connectorCustomizer() {
        return connector -> connector.setProperty("continueResponseTiming", "onRead");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your reply helped me enormously with a tomcat issue I was having where requests were being forwarded by tomcat to http instead of https. I used your example as a template to set the secure attribute to true in https envs and false in http envs. It has worked a treat. Thank you so much for posting.